# Visual Studio 2012 times out randomly during debugging?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-debugging

I have a Visual Studio 2012 project which I do a lot of debugging with. Every so often(multiple times per day), I'll be debugging and Visual Studio will just randomly choke up for 5-10 seconds. Afterwards, I can't evaluate the value of any variables(by the variable it will say `function evaluation timed out`) and single-stepping won't work. The only thing I can do is just restart debugging.

This is a very random issue though. Sometimes it'll happen when I've been debugging for a long 15 minute session... sometimes it'll happen on the first breakpoint I hit. And most of the time, Visual Studio 2012 works... it's just every now and then I get this weird problem. I have no idea how to reproduce it. It's not tied to just one type of object, nor is it even tied to one project. Also, I can open the same project in VS2010 and I've never had this kind of issue

Has this problem been seen elsewhere? Does anyone know of any extra configuration I can do to keep this annoyance from happening?

Comment: This is an entirely normal mishap.  Very common with COM interfaces for example.  Watch expression are evaluated on a separate worker thread so deadlock is always around to time out a watch.  Given that nobody has yet flagged VS2012 as having this problem, you do need to try to find a better diagnostic.

Answer (score 0):

This bug is driving me crazy since every Visual Studio version since 2005 (still with VS 2013 Update 3)! In my case, after the timeout occurred, the process will not continue correctly (the current executed thread dies) and when you want to detach VS, it only lets you do it when you terminate the process.

I don't have a real fix for this issue, but over the years I found out the following which might possibly help you:

- This bug is more likely to occur with big & complex programs.
- It's more likley to occur with multiple threads.
- It's more likely to occur the more you step through the code. Putting a breakpoint somewhere and pressing F5 to jump there is better than stepping all your way to that location.
- When it occurs, don't try to step further in the code, it will kind of randomly jump anywhere and then with the next step, the thread dies. In my case, most of the time only restarting the program will help.
- Try **removing/disabling breakpoints**. The more active breakpoints you have, the higher the risk. Conditional breakpoints are especially "risky".
- Try **closing all windows with watched variables** (Autos, Locals, Watch windows) wherever possible.
- When you need a watch window, **remove all non-needed variables** from it. The more variables that are evaluated, the higher the risk of the hang.
- Uncheck *Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> General -> Enable property evaluation*... That's the most effective way to prevent this bug. However, it makes the debugger rather unusable for me, so I don't want to use it.
- *[For VS 2013 only:]* Try enabling *Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> General -> Use Managed Compatibility Mode*. This will enable the debugging behavior from VS 2012 which I read could be more robust, at least until the issue is fixed in VS 2013.